# Project contains some code snippets under MIT license - can I publish the repo under BSL?

Tags: mit

We've created a project where the bulk of it (70%) is proprietary code. The remaining is code that is public under MIT license. Can we still publish our codebase under a BSL (Business Source License) license?

Comment: What do you mean with 'BSL', is that Boost Software License or is it Business Source License? And how is the MIT-licensed code used in your project (directly copied, linked, as a dependency, ...)?

Comment: @Martin_in_AUT FWIW, the [tag:bsl] applied to the question refers to Boost Software License.

Comment: You cannot change the license of the existing code, no matter if it is only 1% of your project code. However, in all likelihood, the MIT license is "compatible" with the BSL. Why? Because, the MIT license is a permissive license. It's hard to imagine a different license that would make it impossible to also comply with the MIT license for the portions of MIT code that you used in your project.

Answer (score 2):

You can basically do whatever you want with the MIT-licensed code as long as you identify the code and the author properly as required by the MIT license.

The Business Source License can be considered as a proprietary license (source-available license) in the first years, until at the 4th anniversary the 'Change License' comes in place, which is usually GPL.

> Copyright © yyyy, 
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files
> (the “Software”), to deal in the Software without restriction,
> including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge,
> publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software,
> and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so,
> subject to the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED “AS IS”, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
> MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
> IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY
> CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT,
> TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
> SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

Source: [MIT License](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)